# Странное поведение бота

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, faq

Скажите, пожалуйста, а можно как-то угомонить бота, который постоянно поднимает низкокачественные вопросы из архива? Это совершенно бесполезная вещь, а более того, она мешает отвечать на вопросы из приложения: думаешь, новый вопрос, заходишь — нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключить его нельзя, но можно предотвратить повторный подъём вопроса в будущем. Бот вытаскивает на свет вопросы со следующими параметрами:

- рейтинг вопроса неотрицателен
- нет ответов с положительным рейтингом
- есть хотя бы один ответ с нулевым рейтингом
- нет принятого ответа
- вопрос не закрыт

Отсюда следует, что два самых простых способа отправить вопрос в архив, это

- проголосовать "за" ответ, у которого сейчас 0 голосов
- проголосовать "против" вопроса, если у него 0 голосов. Если вопрос низкокачественный, пусть это будет видно.